# itextsharp create link in pdf file to launch a program

Tags: itext

I am using iTextSharp to create PDF files. 
Can I use iTextSharp to create a link in a PDF document that allows the user to launch a program.

Comment: The users of this file will have no problem trusting this file. It is part of the functionalities they requested to launch a certain program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a [Launch action](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=279). I'm the author of the book about iText, and I usually don't talk about this functionality because it's considered being a security hazard (which you point out in your comment: the user really has to trust the PDF).

In iTextSharp, you'd create a launch action like this:

```
    Paragraph p = new Paragraph(
      new Chunk( "Click to open test.txt in Notepad.")
      .SetAction(
        new PdfAction(
          "c:/windows/notepad.exe",
          "test.txt", "open",
          Path.Combine(Utility.ResourceText, "")
        )
    ));
    document.Add(p);
```

Looking at the code, you immediately see a second problem: PDF is supposed to be platform dependent, but we're introducing two dependencies in this code sample:

1. in this sample we only provide a launch action for a PDF opened on Windows (one could add extra properties for other OSs).
2. we assume that the executable is present on the path we defined. That can be a huge problem if you want this PDF to work in every environment.

You'll have to talk this through with your customer to see if they can meet these extra requirements: OS and location of the executable.

Comment: I tried this exact thing in Win10 using the newest version of the iTextSharp5 dll and it doesn't work for me. It doesn't even show a valid link is present when I hover the mouse pointer over the text. Will it work in iText7 or is there some other technique? Thanks :-)

Comment: Launch actions are considered a security hazard. Some PDF viewers don't allow them anymore. In other words: your problem probably isn't related to the PDF creator you are using, but more likely caused by the PDF consumer. If I recall correctly, the ISO committee has considered deprecating launch actions from the PDF standard (meaning PDF viewers might not longer support the feature in the future), but I don't remember if this proposal was approved.